# I am getting the error "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected" in this VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error at the subroutine called NLRegress.  I think the array types are not the same that are being multiplied in the first call in Sub NLRegress.  The Z matrix is the following array [1,0.2,0.04: 1,0.5,0.25: 1,0.8,0.64: 1,1.2,1.44: 1,1.7,2.89: 1,2,4]

This is my code :

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Main()

    Dim x() As Double, y() As Double, n As Integer, p As Integer, _
    a() As Double, syx As Double, r2 As Double, m As Integer, _
    yf() As Double, Z() As Double

    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    For k = 1 To 100
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Cells(k, 1).Value <> "" Then
        n = n + 1 'counts the number of data points
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
    Next k
    For k = 1 To 100
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Cells(k, 1).Value <> "" Then
        p = p + 1 'counts the number of data points
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
    Next k
    If p = n Then
    p = n
    ReDim yf(n)
    Else: MsgBox ("Unequal number of x and y values")
    End If
    ReDim x(n)
    ReDim y(n)
    For i = 1 To n 'Read data for matrix x
            x(i) = _
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next
    For i = 1 To n 'Read data for matrix y
            y(i) = _
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next
    m = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value

    ReDim a(m + 1)
    Call BuildZP(x, Z, n, m)
    Call NLRegress(Z, y, a, n, m)
    Call MultiplyMatrixByVector(Z, a, yf)
End Sub
Sub Fitted_Data(yf, a, x, n)
    Dim q As Integer
    For q = 1 To n
        yf(q) = a(1) + a(2) * x(q) + a(3) * x(q) ^ 2
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Cells(q, 1).Value = yf(q)
    Next
End Sub
Sub NLRegress(Z, y, a, n, m)
Dim er As Double, tol As Double, ZT() As Double, ZTZ() As Double, ZTZI() As Double, ZTY() As Double
er = 0
tol = 0.0001
ReDim ZT(m + 1, n)
Call TransposeMatrix(Z, ZT)
Call MultiplyMatrices(ZT, Z, ZTZ)
Call MatrixInverse(ZTZ, ZTZI, m + 1, tol, er)
Call MultiplyMatrixByVector(ZT, y, ZTY)
Call MultiplyMatrixByVector(ZTZI, ZTY, a)
End Sub

Sub BuildZP(x, Z, n, m)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
ReDim Z(n, m + 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m + 1
            Z(i, j) = x(i) ^ (j - 1)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think one can find you bug with the excerpt you provided - it's most likely in one of the sub procedures that are called in NLRegress. Try to debug your code with F8 (maybe set a breakpoint with F9 in NLRegress) and see what happens...

Answer (score 2):

This answer will probably not solve your issue (see my comment) - but let me nonetheless give you a few best practices that might make programming in VBA easier and maybe prevent such errors in the first place - in your next project.

Try to incorporate the following into your programming

1. Proper indenting: Every time you use a programming structure the encloses another block of code - such as `For`, `If`, `While`, indent the enclosed code block one level further. E.g. your first few lines of code should look like

   ```
   For k = 1 To 100
       If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Cells(k, 1).Value <> "" Then
           n = n + 1    'counts the number of data points
       Else
           Exit For
       End If
   Next k
   ```
2. You are already using `Option Explicit`, which is great. However, you should also properly `Dim` each variable in the procedure/function calls - e.g. `Sub Fitted_Data(yf as Double, ...)`
3. You're using a total of 12 variables in your main procedure. This is a very strong indicator, that your routine is doing too much! Better break it up in to small sub routines and maybe use a few module wide variables - see the example below.
4. The variable names are absolutely meaningless - which makes it hard to debug for you - and almost impossible for outsiders to understand what your code is doing.
5. AFAIK your first 25 rows "only" assign two ranges to an array and check if these are the same size. Using the syntax `x = StartRange.Resize(NumberOfRows).Cells` you can achieve this with much less code - and it executes much faster.
   Same thing goes finding the first blank row - instead of looping, use `StartRange.End(xlDown)` - this will return you the last non-blank row!
   Also, if you want to assign an array to a range, it works the other way round, too: `StartRange.Resize(NumberOfRows) = x`.
6. Hardcoding `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")` will lead to problems when the user changes the worksheet structure, e.g. rename the sheet or insert rows/columns. Better assign the cells A2 and B2 names, e.g. `StartVector1` and then access them with `Range("StartVector1")`. Much more robust - and your code is less cluttered
7. "Don't repeat yourself" (*DRY*). If you see yourself doing the same code twice, make it a separate procedure - e.g your code to count the number of data points
8. No need to use `Call Sub(x, y)` - `Sub x, y` is equivalent to it in VBA
9. Excel function can also be used in VBA. This is especially handy for matrix function. E.g. to transpose an array, you could use this code: `transposedX = worksheetFunctions.Transpose(x)`

Here's the code structure with the first few

```
Option Explicit

Private mVec1() As Double 'Better give a better name representing the target content of variable
Private mVec2() As Double 'I use m as a prefix to indicate module wide scoped variables

Public Sub SubDoingSomething() 'Use a name that tells the reader what the sub does

    LoadVectors

    BuildZP Z, n, m 'use proper variable names here

    NLRegress Z, y, a, n, m 'and maybe use some more module wide variables that you don't need to pass

    MultiplyMatrixByVector Z, a, yf

End Sub

Private Sub LoadVectors()
    Dim count1 As Long, count2 As Long

    count1 = GetRowLength(Range("StartVector1"))
    count2 = GetRowLength(Range("StartVector2"))

    If count1 <> count2 Then
        MsgBox ("Unequal number of x and y values")
        End
    End If

    mVec1 = Range("StartVector1").Resize(count1).Cells
    mVec2 = Range("StartVector2").Resize(count2).Cells

End Sub

Private Function GetRowLenght(rng As Range)
    If rng.Offset(1) = "" Then
        GetRowLength = 1
    Else
        GetRowLength = rng.End(xlDown).Row - rng.Row + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Agreed, especially with #4 - every time I see a post with difficult to understand variable names here I just click back. It's not worth it to me to try to decipher broken code with variables which make no sense. Great answer